# How to make fading/parallax actionbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, swipe, whatsapp

I'm creating an app and I want to implement two actionbars like those in Whatsapp.

Can someone help mee?

I need the code with explanation, or only the code

I'm learning to program :)

Sorry for my poor english, I'm from Brazil

[image: ActionBar #1]
[image: ActionBar #2]

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the following libraries

- https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar
- https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll
- https://github.com/bydavy/android-parallax-example

Each has an example app, so that should help you understand how to use it.

Comment: Thank You
I found this library [Android-ObservableScrollView](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView)